# Weblogic 12.1.3.0 domain creation- config.sh ends Immediately after starting

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c, weblogic-10.x

I am trying to create *Weblogic 12.1.3.0* domain by running `config.sh` in console mode since my Linux servers doesn't support GUI. When I run the script, it exits immediately without any error or any information being displayed.

I ran the `config.sh` script with and without mode parameter. I also ran the script with absolute path. But did not work.

1. `-bash-4.1$ ./config.sh -mode=console`  //When I run this, in 2 sec it exits and go to next line
2. `-bash-4.1$`

Can somebody please help me with this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you edit the shell script and add some debug output traces to help to see where it stops ?

Comment: Thank you for the response. But config.sh is a read only file for my user group. I am not sure if I will be able to make changes to it, but will try that.

Comment: Adding to my query, does Weblogic 12.1.3.0 supports console mode?

Comment: yes it does even if the best way is to use wlst.

Comment: Do you have permission to run it? the `'x'` in `wrx`?

Comment: Thank you all for the response. I have found out what is causing the issue, 12.1.3.0 is not supporting console mode at least in my case.I found this from logs (/usr/tmp) that display is casuing config to exit. So I connected to server using 'BluezoneX' tool, instead of 'putty'. This supports GUI mode of Oracle wizard and when I run 'config.sh' now from this tool, it opens the Oracle Config Wizard in GUI and I can proceed. But one issue I face now is that I cannot run 'config.sh' in 'sudo'  mode. I can run it only from my User Id

Comment: this is correct, weblogic needs a user that is not a root. You can't sudo weblogic installation and can't sudo any configuration direct related to weblogic

Comment: It is possible to configurate domains in weblogic with only command line but the correct script is not  'config.sh'. From the readme you first need to run setWLSEnv.sh them create a folder for the domain, enter it and run JAVA_HOME/bin/java weblogic.Server (that last part dosen't work for me)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a WLS zip installer then you need to use the configure.sh script to create a basic domain instead of the config.sh script. Even though the config.sh script is present it will not work. So, you might have the WLS zip package and there is the problem.